# How should I upgrade the version of Python to latest release

Tags: python-3, python-2.x

I would like to re-bind Apache fCGI to python3.7 instead of Python2.7. I saw the following error message while my script used type-hinting.

```
AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Raspbian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

How should I upgrade the binding? I have **both versions of Python Installed**.

Comment: Are you using the latest Raspberry Pi OS fully updated?

Comment: Yes. I have both versions of Python installed, and OS is fully upgraded. I do not need python2 (that came by default).

Comment: Welcome -- but this is really a python+linux+apache question, which is a far larger realm than the Raspberry Pi, the brand of hardware being tangential or irrelevant.  I am also certain that your solution is not a good or canonical one and a better one would have been found if you researched this as a python/linux/apache issue including asking about it on our parent site Stack Overflow or U&L, where it would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually need FastCGI, you could run Python scripts via plain old CGI:

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
```

Then simply start your scripts with

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

and Apache should run them with Python 3 interpreter.

Actually, you have lots of options here (`mod_cgi`, `mod_fcgid`, `mod_fastcgi`, `mod_wsgi`, `mod_python`), and [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/webservers.html) provide a good overview of them.

Comment: It seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

[Solved] and thank you all. There was no straight forward solution, but it worked finally. I uninstalled "python" (which was 2.7), and linked to new version:

```
ln -s -f /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Then, recompiled the wsgi:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.7.1.tar.gz
tar zxf 4.7.1.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-4.7.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo chmod 644 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
sudo a2enmod wsgi
sudo systemctl restart apache2
cd ..
# rm -rf /tmp/mod_wsgi-4.7.1/
```

Then the [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) test /info/ route showed new version of python 3 under Apache. The app.py had a starting line: `#!/usr/bin/python3` as:

[app.py]:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/info/", methods=["GET"])
def info():
    info = {
        "VERSION": sys.version,
    }
    return json.dumps(info)
```

Comment: It's great that it worked, but know that replacing Python 2 with Python 3 in this way may lead to subtle bugs in software which expects Python 2 to be there.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the reminder. But I had portability issue of moving python3 (code written in Windows) to run as a web service under Apache2. Is there a way of identifying the dependencies of python2? Again, you figured out an important point, where I should have both versions of python existing, but Apache should bind to Python3.